# Wordpress title very long without space between letters

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I have a small problem with wordpress title 
[image]

The problem is that the title leaves the h2 tag

help me if you can

Comment: Try using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` in your `<h2>` tag. You will need to override the original CSS. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: thank you so much it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use that code for h2

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using css this is not right way i think, You use this function " `wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );` "otherwise `wordwrap()`PHP function using this function you can wrap or trim your dynamic content instead off "OVERFLOW: HIDDEN" css.